# Is it possible to emulate remote URL behavior using local browser object?

Tags: javascript, redoc

I am using Redoc standalone with our API server. After `redoc.standalone.js` is loaded, `redoc` tries to fetch `schema.yaml` from the API server. However, our server needs an `Authorization` header with token, which `Redoc` does not include by default. I am looking for a solution to either download and save the schema file locally or add the `Authorization` header as a default header for all requests sent from the page. Is there another way to read `schema.yaml` locally by `Redoc` without making a request to the private API server? Below is the current HTML code I am using with Redoc:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Example API</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300,400,700|Roboto:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
      <style>
         body {
         margin: 0;
         padding: 0;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <redoc spec-url='https://api.example.com/schema.yaml'></redoc>
      <script src="redoc.standalone.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done with a different approach. Instead of using the react rendering with Redoc, build the HTML documentation with the `redocly build-docs` command (see docs: https://redocly.com/docs/cli/commands/build-docs/) from a location where you do have access to the schema, or can download it before generating the docs. Then publish the HTML output.

(disclaimer, I work at Redocly, who make Redoc)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, but building of static HTML brings extra costs and problems: what person in team should generate static contents? Or it should be CI pipeline? What is timing of HTML generating? on merge to `develop`? on release? Where implement pipeline? etc... So it will be a really convenient feature if you add a way to customize security settings

Comment: Specifically in the CLI docs, you might also find the resolve feature useful https://redocly.com/docs/cli/configuration/#resolve-object if you do go that route.

It feels wrong to plug a commercial option in response to a question about an open source tool, but just in case it's helpful in for your situation: Redocly also has a hosted API docs option that can accept/fetch an OpenAPI from a selection of sources, and host it. More information https://redocly.com/reference/